# Why when showing the keyboard, occur a white blank space before?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, keyboard

In the Flutter, why when showing the keyboard, occur a white blank space before. This is normal or bug, how to resolve the problem?. (both android and ios)

That white blank space was overlaid by the keyboard after. 
It only appears in a few milliseconds, but on the native, I don't see that.

My code:

```
class CategoryPage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _CategoryPageState createState() => _CategoryPageState();
}

class _CategoryPageState extends State<CategoryPage> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: double.infinity,
      color: Colors.redAccent,
      child: TextField(
        decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Name Text Field'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[See picture for more details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V4Wdl.gif)

Comment: Where is the blank space? Your picture doesn't have any blank spaces? In TextField or in the keyboard? Do you mean top and bottom padding in the TextField?

Comment: Hi @Vinoth Vino, that white blank space was overlaid by the keyboard after. 
It only appears in a few milliseconds, but on the native, I don't see that.